# Modifying Transliterator Rules

Tags: input-source, sip

I'm using the MacOS' Tamil language input tool. However this question can be answered in a generic way.

I am trying to make some changes in the rules under this folder.

`/System/Library/Input Methods/TamilIM.app/Contents/Resources`

How do start? Meanwhile I'm looking to solve the SIP issue by remounting the file system.

Will manually editing the `Transliterator.txt` file would work or do I have to compile the binary?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to just edit Transliterator.txt.  [I did this once](https://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2007/12/os-x-105-leopard-fixing-anjal-tamil.html) long ago and it worked.  But things may have changed since then...

Comment: Thank you Tom, having browsed about this issue for a while, realised you’re a notable person in the macOS community related such issues. I indeed was finding a way to reach you. Anjal have few minor issues. I’ll let you know how it goes.